# PHP parse JSON from array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to grab a key (Status) out of an array that is formatted with json.

**Array**

```
Array ( [0] => Running correlate.sh [1] => /var/www/html/blah/Correlation/classes [2] => Executing java command with JSON pps null 93993939 John Smith John Smith 1234 M 01-1-1990 [3] => last name is SMITH [4] => configFilePath is null [5] => feedName is pps [6] => [7] => select distinct(null), guid , scx_eid, emplid, national_ID, last_name, birthdate, first_name from table_a where guid is not null and ( scx_eid = '12345678' or emplid = 'null' or (substr(national_ID,length(national_ID)-3,4) = '1234' and upper(last_name) = 'SMITH') or (substr(national_ID, length(national_ID)-3,4) = '1234' and birthdate = '90-null-01-1') or (birthdate = '90-null-01-1' and upper(last_name) = 'SMITH') or (upper(first_name) = 'JOHN' and upper(last_name) = 'ZSCHEILE')) [8] => first match {} [9] => [10] => select distinct(null), guid , eid, last4ssn, lastname, dob, firstname from table_c where guid is not null and ( eid = '12345678' or (substr(last4ssn,length(last4ssn)-3,4) = '1234' and upper(lastname) = 'SMITH') or (substr(last4ssn, length(last4ssn)-3,4) = '1234' and dob = '90-null-01-1') or (dob = '90-null-01-1' and upper(lastname) = 'SMITH') or (upper(firstname) = 'JOHN' and upper(lastname) = 'SMITH')) [11] => second match {} [12] => [13] => select distinct(null), guid , eid, emplid from table_d where guid is not null and ( eid = '12345678' or emplid = 'null') [14] => third match {} [15] => ldapMatch list is null [16] => returning firstMatch as {} [17] => [18] => Final Status:{Status=DISPUTED, GUID=[]} [19] => {"Status":"DISPUTED","GUID":[]}exiting script )
```

**What I need**

```
$status = 'DISPUTED';
```

**Update**

I was able to change the java so it outputs this below. How could I explode this to get two variables back, $status and $GUID?

```
{"Status":"DISPUTED","GUID":[]}
{"Status":"CONFIRMED","GUID":[G010908712]}
{"Status":"DISPUTED","GUID":[]}
{"Status":"DISPUTED","GUID":[]}
{"Status":"CONFIRMED","GUID":[G403057017]}
{"Status":"CONFIRMED","GUID":[G104522939]}
{"Status":"CONFIRMED","GUID":[G020669940]}
```

Comment: What result are you getting? What result are you expecting?

Comment: nothing gets set. I expect $status=DISPUTED

Answer (score 1):

If the string `exiting script` is really at the end of your JSON that will mess things up. Otherwise, json_decode takes a second argument to specify that you want an array, not an object:

```
$json_a = json_decode($array[19], true);
```

Comment: @Jeffrey You need to figure out where it's coming from and remove it then, because it makes your JSON invalid by being there, so json_decode can't work with it. You could strip it off the end if you want to, but that is a more hackish temporary solution. If you really want to solve the problem find out where it's coming from.

Comment: I changed the java so that it spits back the last line of the array as json. I tried your code above, but it only gets DISPUTED.

Comment: @Jeffrey I thought DISPUTED was what you wanted?

Comment: my update, above in the question, better articulates what is needed

Comment: @Jeffrey It doesn't explain anything to me. You have 7 statuses and GUID arrays, but you haven't said which status and guid you want. You want two variables for all 7?